# Renaming files with find ... -exec sh -c doesn't work on specific system - "Bad substitution"

Tags: bash, shell, find, rename

On one system (mine) I have `find (GNU findutils) 4.8.0`, and when I run the following command

```bsh
find . -name '*.cpp' -exec sh -c 'f=$0; echo mv "$f" "${f/cpp/CPP}"' {} \;
```

I obtain a list like this:

```bsh
mv ./stuff.cpp ./stuff.CPP
mv ./main.cpp ./main.CPP
...
```

one line for each matching file.

(By the way, can you point to an surely existing answer where I understand why changing `\;` to `\+` results in one single file being processed, so that the output is `mv ./stuff.cpp ./stuff.CPP`?)

On another system I'm not totally aware of, I see `find` is `find (GNU findutils) 4.6.0.225-235f`, and the above command gives these errors:

```
./unittest/tTransform3.cpp: 1: ./unittest/tTransform3.cpp: Bad substitution
./unittest/tTransform2.cpp: 1: ./unittest/tTransform2.cpp: Bad substitution
...
```

Can anybody help me understand what might be going wrong on the latter system?

Comment: `man find (-exec option)` explains '`';'` versus `+` to terminate the embedded command. + adds multiple filename args (similar to xargs), ';' does one arg per command iteration. Also ; needs to be quoted (as it is a shell terminator which would prematurely terminate the whole find command), + is less special to the shell.

Comment: There are much better ways of doing bulk renames.  Best is to use perl `rename` (aka `prename` or `file-rename`):  e.g. `rename -n 's/\.cpp$/.CPP/' *.cpp`  or `find . -name '*.cpp' -exec rename -n 's/\.cpp$/.CPP/' {} +`.   The `-n` is for a dry-run. Remove (or replace with `-v`) when you're sure it's going to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sh` is probably dash or another POSIX shell in your second system. `${var/pat/rep}` isn't [a POSIX parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02), so a POSIX `sh` doesn't need to have it. Since this system has GNU find, it likely also has bash, so use `bash -c` instead (as you always should when using bashisms).

Comment: That's right! Thank you very much. By the way, now that you've prompted me, I've looked at `man sh` and verified it is `dash` indeed.